# Kendo ui Map not working with SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, jquery

I have to use the kendo ui map for the publishing site.
I have added all the references like css, js and added all the html Map rendering code and added with the script editor, it only shows the **navigator** and **zoom in/out** buttons.
So please let me know either its possible or not?
But I got one article which is for office 365 as -[Click here](https://richross.me/2014/12/29/office-365-and-kendo-ui-map-control/)
And also it's working fine with **html** and **asp.net**
**Thanks in Advance!!!**